# CircularProgressIndicator: Can't resize properly

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

My code:

```
Row (
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().padding(16.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    Checkbox(
        checked = checked,
        enabled = habit.enabled,
        onCheckedChange = { checked = !checked },
        modifier = Modifier.size(23.dp).padding(end = 8.dp)
    )
    CircularProgressIndicator(
        progress = animatedProgress,
        modifier = Modifier.size(23.dp).padding(end = 8.dp)
    )
    Icon(
        imageVector = habit.icon,
        contentDescription = null,
        modifier = Modifier.padding(end = 8.dp)
    )
    Text(
        text = LocalContext.current.getString(habit.stringResourceId),
        maxLines = 1
    )
}
```

Here's what it outputs:

[image]

I want it to be the same size as checkbox and icon, but it does that for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each item of Row with Box layout, Use below code snippet.

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun Test() {
Row(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .padding(16.dp),
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
) {
    val modifier = Modifier
        .padding(end = 8.dp)
    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        Checkbox(
            checked = true,
            enabled = true,
            onCheckedChange = {},
            modifier = Modifier.size(23.dp)
        )
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        CircularProgressIndicator(
            progress = 0.9f,
            strokeWidth = 2.dp,
            modifier = Modifier.size(23.dp)
        )
    }

    Box(
        modifier = modifier,
    ) {
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Info,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(23.dp)
        )
    }

    Text(
        text = "Some Text Goes Here",
        maxLines = 1
    )
  }
}
```

This above code snippet will yield result like this.

[image: Result]